# Exception mapper works for some situations in my jersey/spring app, but not in others

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I have gotten exception mapper to work in part of my jersey/spring application, but it does not work in other parts for some reason and I don't understand why because it is implemented in the same way.

I want my own `UserNameIsNotUnique` exception to be thrown when `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown which is mapped with exception mapper and returns an http response.

I have gotten this to work in other parts of my program with similar code, but for some reason this one does not work. I am wondering if it has something to do with `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

Whenever I call this method with a non unique username, `UsernameIsNotUniqueException` is thrown, but it appears to not be mapped, and I get a `404` response instead of the response that is used in the exception mapper.

This is what the method looks like that throws the exception that I want mapped.

```
public Employee createEmployee(String name, String email, String username, String password, double latvalue, double longvalue, String image, String street, String city, String country) throws ServiceException, UserDoesNotExistException, UserNameIsNotUniqueException, IllegalUserNameException {
    log.info("createEmployee(): email: "+email);
    Employee employee=null;
    try {
        if (userNameIsAReservedWord(username)) {
            throw new IllegalUserNameException("This username is a reserved word: " + username);
        }
        employee = new Employee(name, email, username, latvalue, longvalue, image, street, city, country);
        Employee savedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
        employeeInfoService.createEmployeeInfo(savedEmployee.getId(), password);
        return savedEmployee;
    } catch (IllegalUserNameException e) {
        log.warn("** SERVICE EXCEPTION ** FOR METHOD: createEmployee()");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.warn("** SERVICE EXCEPTION ** FOR METHOD: createEmployee()");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ServiceException("** SERVICE EXCEPTION ** FOR METHOD: createEmployee()", e);
    }
    catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
        log.warn("** GENERAL EXCEPTION ** FOR METHOD: createEmployee()");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new UserNameIsNotUniqueException("A username that is already used was attempted to be created a profile with: "+username);
    }
}
```

This is what the exception mapper class looks like.

```
@Provider
public class UserNameIsNotUniqueExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<UserNameIsNotUniqueException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(UserNameIsNotUniqueException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.EXPECTATION_FAILED)
                .entity("Sombody is using this user name already, please select a unique username.").build();
    }

}
```

This is what the Exception looks like.

```
public class UserNameIsNotUniqueException extends Exception{

public UserNameIsNotUniqueException(String msg, Exception e){
    super(msg, e);
}

public UserNameIsNotUniqueException(String msg){
    super(msg);
}
}
```

Any help as to why this is not working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as that I did not register the ExceptionMapper class with jersey. I did this with the register() method.